# Power BI forecasting

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I go by doing the following in Power Bi.

I have three machines...

Machine 1 has 100 customers and a total repair rate of 5% over 3 years.

Machine 2 has 400 customers and a total repair rate of 3% over 2 years.

Machine 3 had 50 customers and a total repair rate of 2% over 1 year.

I want to see what my repair rate would become if I changed all the machine 2 customers to machine 3. So in theory the repair rate for machine 2 customers would decrease and the total repair rate for machine 3 would be something like 2.5% when changed. How do I write the code in power bi when my data looks like the following.

| Customer # | Repair | Machine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | 2 |
| 2 | No | 3 |
| 3 | Yes | 3 |
| 4 | No | 2 |
| 5 | No | 1 |
| 6 | No | 1 |

Comment: What do you mean by "Repair rate"? How do you calculate it?
To answer your question, you'd create a calculated column in Customer 
IF([Machine]=2,3,[Machine]). Then you'd use that Calculated Column in your matrix.